# If two values on the same row exist in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table A

```
+=========+=========+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+=========+=========+
|    A    |    1    |
+---------+---------+
|    A    |    2    |
+---------+---------+
|    C    |    3    |
+---------+---------+
|    A    |    3    |
+---------+---------+
```

I have another table B

```
+=========+=========+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+=========+=========+
|    A    |    3    |
+---------+---------+
|    A    |    2    |
+---------+---------+
|    C    |    6    |
+---------+---------+
|    D    |    4    |
+---------+---------+
```

I want to check for table B, 
If the values in column 1 AND column 2 are in table A, on the same line return 1.

Obviously I cannot use a Vlookup as I am lokoing for 2 values. Any idea how to complete this?

Comment: Just write a VBA function to check if the row values exist in the other table

Comment: Look at the "Related" topics shown on the right of your screen. Google for "Vlookup with multiple criteria".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following formula works:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,E:E,E1)-1
```

I was using `=COUNTIF(B:B,B1,E:E,E1)` and getting an error, therefore thought this would not work, but it does.